# Why "EntityKey does not match the corresponding value in the EntityKey"?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

First I'd like to show the corresponding code snippet. When it comes to objCtx.AttachTo() it throws me an error:

```
Error: "The object cannot be attached because the value of a property that is a part of the EntityKey does not match the corresponding value in the EntityKey."

        // convert string fragIds to Guid fragIds 
        var fragIdsGuids = docGenResult.FragIds.Select(c => new Guid(c)).ToList();

        //add each fragment to document))))
        foreach (Guid fragIdsGuid in fragIdsGuids)
        {
            var fragment = new Fragment() { EntityKey = new EntityKey("DocTestObjectContext.Fragments", "ID", fragIdsGuid) };
            objCtx.AttachTo("Fragments", fragment);
        }
        objCtx.SaveChanges();
```

I've checked everything and I'm not missing any primary key.

However I need some words to explain why I think I have to do it this way.

I'm using EF4 in a C# Environment.
I have a many to many relationship between two tables, Document and Fragments(Primary key "ID") (Documents can have many fragments and a fragment can be a part of many documents)
The Entity Model works fine for me.

However when I try to add a new document to the DB I already have the IDs of the related Fragments in my hand. For adding a new document to the DB I have to call each Fragmentobject and add it to the mapped reference in my document-object. This is a bottleneck because a document can have more than 1000 fragments. The Consequence is that I need 1sec per document. Not much, but I have to create more than 3000 documents and saving this second would result in more speed.

Hopefully you know what's wrong in here.

Thanks.
Thomas

**1st edit:**

here is the solution wich actually works. I would like to avoid to load all the fragments and instead just save the fragment GUID I already have in the mapping table.

```
        // convert string fragIds to Guid fragIds 
        var fragIdsGuids = docGenResult.FragIds.Select(c => new Guid(c)).ToList();
        // get responding entities from Fragment table
        var fragmentList = objCtx.Fragments.Where(c => fragIdsGuids.Contains(c.ID)).ToList();
        foreach (var fragment in fragmentList)
        {
            doc.Fragment.Add(fragment);
        }
        objCtx.SaveChanges();
```

**2nd edit:**

I have the feeling that it is not really clear what I try to do.
However I would like to link/reference existing fragments in a Fragment-table to a coressponding Document in a Document table. The Document I'd like to reference is a new one. The document to Fragment table has an many to many relationship. This relationship has a linking table on the database. In the model it is correctly modeled as a many to many relationship. That's fine.

So far so good. What works is what you can see under my first edit. I have to load all the necessary fragments for a document by their id

```
// get responding entities from Fragment table
    var fragmentList = objCtx.Fragments.Where(c => fragIdsGuids.Contains(c.ID)).ToList();
```

After that I'm able to add them to my document entity:

```
foreach (var fragment in fragmentList)
    {
        doc.Fragment.Add(fragment);
    }
```

But why the hell do I have to load the whole entity (fragments) only to link it to a new document. Why do not tell the EntityStateManager "Dude, here you have some Fragment IDs, link them!"?

Further I tried to follow the MSDN article mentioned by Adrian in the comments. This doesn't worked out for me.

Comment: Is the Link table mapped in your model ( is it with PayLoad)?

Comment: In the model I can see the many to many connection. The linking table between both tables is not visualized.

Comment: Another question came around from a friend... the docGenResult variable has nothing to do with any ObjectContext.

Comment: Sorry mate I didn't. I think, it's impossible to do what I want. Maybe there is a misunderstanding between me and the EF.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try this:

```
    var fragment = new Fragment {ID = fragIdsGuid};
    //fragment.EntityKey.Dump(); // -- this should be null
    objCtx.AttachTo("Fragments", fragment);
   //fragment.EntityKey.Dump(); // -- shows the EntityKey object, created after the object is attached
```

The Dump function is from LinqPad

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately did doesn't worked for me. An InvalidOperationException was thrown: "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key." :(

Comment: The problem is a Fragment with that Guid already exists in your context and while you are trying to attach it, it gives this error. Either you loaded it with other document, either the Guids are not unique.

Comment: You are right. But how can I tell the ObjectStateManager that he should accept my key of an existing fragment without loading the whole fragment? I'd like to avoid the loading process of all the fragments. I don't need them except to link them to my new document.

Comment: see if the item is tracked by context looking at ObjectStateManager

Comment: Thanks again but this doesn't work out for me either. Sure I took notice of this MSDN article. But maybe it is not possible to do what I want. I try to explain it in more detail in a second update of my question.